# Recommending deletion

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users

It happens fairly frequently that some one with very few reputation points posts an "answer" to a question that the community feels was more suited to being a "comment". Some one then starts an action to delete this answer on the ground it it isn't an answer because it's a comment.

Rather than just deleting these posts, which sometimes contain useful information, wouldn't it be better if there was an option to convert an answer into a comment (of the main post, by default)? Or alternatively, allow users with insufficient reputation point to post comments that have to first approved in the same way that edits need approval before they are posted.

Comment: Mods have this power. So flagging leads to that.

Comment: @percusse Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: I agree that stating `this is rather a comment than an answer` is not really helpful for <50 rep users, as those cannot post comments, however, the 50 rep boundary is nevertheless useful, as it prevents spam comments (at least I have not found encountered one the whole time being at TeX.SX!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the conversion of a non-answer to a comment, flag the post for moderator attention and request a conversion. Note that [10K-users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) are able to view deleted posts and could flag them for conversion even then.

The communication privilege that allows you to [comment anywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) is reached at 50 reputation. [For some, perhaps most](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147529/168244), this is considered quite minimal to reach when you *contribute* to the site. That is, *answer* a question or ask one.

<sub>Remember that [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s like these would have to be considered at a network-wide level. And, since there exists a way for converting non-answers to comments, it would be difficult to justify the need for something else.</sub>

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right: If I posted an answer that should've been a comment because I was not yet able to comment, I can flag it myself so it'll be converted to a comment?
I was looking to convert it myself, which I didn't manage (the reason I'm here now). Is there a specific way to flag it?

It's about this question here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413381/131277

Sorry for bothering you, I appreciate any help!

Comment: @EmeraJade: Yes. Flag it for moderator attention and request that it be converted.